# In python can I use comprehension in print just like in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, list-comprehension

I want to ask that if we can use comprehension in print statement in python.
Just like:

```
print(i for i in range(10))
```

This gives me an error. Is there any way that we can compress our code by comprehensive printing ??

Comment: print([i for i in range(10)])

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has no error, it returns a generator. Instead, make it a list:

```
print([i for i in range(10)])
```

or better, with the list function:

```
print(list(range(10)))
```